# playing android audio from a specified time

Tags: android

How can i play audio from a specified time ?
I have a prerecorded audio and i want to play it from a specific time to a specific time.
I have tried seekTo function in MediaPlayer but it doesnt seem to work.
`mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mPlayer.setDataSource(PATH_FILE + selectedAudio);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.seekTo(2);
            mPlayer.start();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error in startPlaying method");
        }`

Thanks in advance